# I have this python turtle based code where if you input a number, the shape moves to a specific coordinate but only moves to else:

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

this is what I have so far.
any help is appreciated

```
from turtle import *
import random
import turtle

ws = turtle.Screen()
ws.bgcolor("SkyBlue")



shape = Shape('compound')
shapesize(stretch_len=15,stretch_wid=15)

print(input('Enter your specified cords:   '))
userreturn = input

pen=turtle.pen
def draw2(x,y):
    penup()
    pencolor('blue')
    ws.update
    if userreturn == ('2'):
        turtle.goto(9000,9)
    elif userreturn == ('23'):
        turtle.goto(23,51)
    elif userreturn == ('51'):
        turtle.goto(51,39)
    else:
        turtle.goto(200,2)



turtle.onclick(draw2)
turtle.mainloop()
turtle.bye
```

I tried to make it so that if the input is the given specific numbers, it will take the shape to a random place, but the Any specific number i type will just end up in bringing the results of `else:`.

Comment: You must first execute `userreturn = input('Enter your...` and then `print(userreturn)`. `userreturn = input` makes no sense.

Comment: yoo tysm, im completely new and im doing this for middle school and you helped me out.